# How to implement amchart's lazy loading when getting data from an API

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, amcharts4

I'm trying to to create a timeline with the xychart and lineseries.
But there is problem . I get my chart data from our backend API but the data is immensely  large and showing all this data at once can cause performance issues.
For example we have a time period like from December 10th to December 20th and we have 1000 series stacked on top of each other in that period.this is overwhelming to show at once.is there a way to get the data gradually for example by  scrolling up and whenever reaching the top get the next batch of series?
Thank your for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could find, you can actually group your data and make group items after a certain time interval and hence you don't need to worry about this thing.

For more info, you can check [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/date-axis/#Dynamic_data_item_grouping)

Comment: thanks for your response, this probably wont work in my case because i'm using this charts a overall system status chart and can't afford to minimize data   especially when my data is not a column but a series of horizontal stacked on top of each other and spanned across a date axis